# Detect the id of a dynamically created input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am making a contact list using JavaScript and I create an edit button for every entry in the table.

How can I detect the `id` of the specific edit button I click on?

```js
rows[id] = table.insertRow(addRow);
cell1[id] = rows[id].insertCell(0);
cell2[id] = rows[id].insertCell(1);
cell3[id] = rows[id].insertCell(2);
cell4[id] = rows[id].insertCell(3);
cell1[id].innerHTML = contact.name;
cell2[id].innerHTML = contact.email;
cell3[id].innerHTML = contact.phone;

editButtons[id] = document.createElement('input');
editButtons[id].classList.add("editButton");
editButtons[id].type = "image";
editButtons[id].src = "edit.png"
editButtons[id].id = id;
editButtons[id].addEventListener('click', updateInForm);
```

Comment: Just access the `.id` property of that object.

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to give you the exact answer you are looking for without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but you are probably looking for `event.target`.

Take a look a the [documentation for DOM invent handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers).

Specifically, [this part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handlers_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value):

> When the event handler is specified as an HTML attribute, the
> specified code is wrapped into a function with the following
> parameters:
>
> event — for all event handlers except onerror. event, source, lineno,
> colno, and error for the onerror event handler. Note that the event
> parameter actually contains the error message as a string.

The event object will have a `target` property that contains the element that triggered the event.

also

> When the event handler is invoked, the this keyword inside the handler
> is set to the DOM element on which the handler is registered. For more
> details, see the this keyword documentation.